# How to send and receive MySQL data for dynamic input fiels

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I was wondering how someone would send and receive input data to and from a MySQL database when the form that is being submitted can have additional fields added to it (So one order form might have 10 input fields and another might have 30). Here is a snippet to give you an idea of what I am talking about - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/M84r7/

I saw an post about using arrays but it was from 4 years ago and am wanting to make sure whatever I do is still using best practices. Any and all help or ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="fence">
    <div name="inputFence" class="inputFence">
        <legend><strong>Fence Description</strong>
        </legend>
        <label>Footage:
            <input name="footage_1" class="footage" />
        </label>
        <label>Fence Height</label>
        <select name="fenceHeight_1" class="fenceHeight">
            <option value="select">Select Fence Height</option>
            <option value="6" id="fH6">6 Ft.</option>
            <option value="8" id="fH8">8 Ft.</option>
        </select>
        <legend><strong>Post Type</strong>
        </legend>
        <label>Post Quantity:
            <input name="postQuantity_1" class="postQuantity" />
        </label>
        <label>Picket Quantity
            <input name="picketQuantity_1" class="picketQuantity" />
        </label>
</fieldset>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAddFence" value="Add Another Fence" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDelFence" value="Remove Fence" />
</div>
</form>
```

JS

```
//Dynamic Fence Input Fields
$('#btnAddFence').click(function () {

    // create the new element via clone()
    var newElem = $('.inputFence:last').clone();

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicable" input field
    $('.inputFence:last').after(newElem);

    // enable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDelFence').removeAttr('disabled');

    //get the input name and split into array (assuming your clone is always last)
    var parts = $('.fenceHeight:last').attr('name').split("_");
    //change the second element of the array to be one higher
    parts[1]++;
    //join back into a string and apply to the new element
    $('.fenceHeight:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));

    //do the same for other two inputs
    parts = $('.postQuantity:last').attr('name').split("_");
    parts[1]++;
    $('.postQuantity:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));

    parts = $('.footage:last').attr('name').split("_");
    parts[1]++;
    $('.footage:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));

    parts = $('.6foc:last').attr('name').split("_");
    parts[1]++;
    $('.6foc:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));

    parts = $('.railQuantity:last').attr('name').split("_");
    parts[1]++;
    $('.railQuantity:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));

});

$('#btnDelFence').click(function () {
    //remove the last inputFence
    $('.inputFence:last').remove();

    // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
    if ($('.inputFence').length == 1) $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: what kind of "extra" fields"? mysql couldn't care less about your form. It's the PHP code that accepts the submission and formulates the mysql query that does.

Comment: There is a button that basically copies the existing fields ("footage_1", "fenceHeight_1", etc) and then pastes them underneath while adding one to the their number suffix.

Comment: I can imagine figuring out a way to send the input information (Anish Joseph just pointed out what looks like a great way to do it) I just don't get how I can call that information from MySQL and then have the form dynamically create any additional input fields that are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you have an unknown number of fields and you are looking for an easy way to send them to MySql.  So I'm assuming you are calling a stored procedure but don't know how to deal with the unknown parameters.  I would take the form and either serialize it into JSON or turn all the $_POST values into a XML object.  Then you would only need to pass that single object into your MySql stored procedure.  Once inside you could use some loops and XML function to do what you have to do.  This way it wouldn't matter if your submitting 10 fields or 100 fields, the call to the stored proc would always be the same.  I do this with a site and it works pretty good.  Not on that PC to where I can get the code right now though.  These might help....

To turn the PHP $_POST into XML: http://davidwalsh.name/watch-post-save-php-post-data-xml
Some MySql XML function to use once you're inside the stored proc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html

I could help more later when I get on my other PC.. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** Here is how I grab all $_POST data and turn it into a valid XML document...

```
//Grab all the POST info, turn it into a valid XML object and store it
$postData = null;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && count($_POST) > 0) $postData = assocArrayToXML('POST_DATA',$_POST);
//The assocArrayToXML returns the XML object with page breaks, we need a stright non-breaking string
//so that the flexigrid can display the results properly.
$postData = str_replace(chr(13), '', $postData);
$postData = str_replace(chr(10), '', $postData);
```

And this is the assocArrayToXML function...

```
function assocArrayToXML($root_element_name,$ar)
{
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><{$root_element_name}></{$root_element_name}>");
  $f = create_function('$f,$c,$a','
          foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
              if(is_array($v)) {
                  $ch=$c->addChild(htmlspecialchars($k));
                  $f($f,$ch,$v);
              } else {
                  $c->addChild($k,htmlspecialchars($v));
              }
          }');
  $f($f,$xml,$ar);
  return $xml->asXML();
}
```

Comment: You're awesome. This sounds like it will cover all the bases. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you decide to serialize into JSON and pass that instead of XML then you will need something like this in MySql to extract the name/value pairs: http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/mysql-5-7-sql-functions-for-json-udf/

Comment: And please feel free to post any other pointers lol. I'm studying up on JSON and XML right now but any pointers are always welcome.

Comment: Added some more info for ya.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that look's awesome. I just saw this so I will have to get to it in the morning but I really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you give me some additional detail as to what $f, $c, and $a are?

Comment: How do you call the JQuery variable on the php page? Do you make a hidden input field and then use JQuery to set its value?

Comment: I don't understand your last question.  PHP runs on the server first, it produces html, css, javascript (jQuery).  What code specifically are you asking about?

Comment: I was trying to figure out how I could get the xml object created from your answer to the database I am trying to save it in. So I was thinking maybe you'd gather the POST data, turn it into an xml object, and then somehow tie it to a variable on my php page to be able to send it to the MySQL database (I am completely new to this have nothing but internet articles to go on this lol).

Comment: Yes, in the example code the '$postData' variable will end up containing the XML object which contains alllll your fields you posted.  You pass that to a MySql stored proc.  Have you ever written/called a MySql stored proc before?

Comment: Oooooh, okay. I was trying to serialize them then tie them to a hidden input field and load _that_ into MySQL

Comment: And no, can't say that I have, but I now have a pretty good idea of what to look for and at least now I know why what I was doing wasn't working. Well it loaded in the fields but the values were all missing.

Comment: Email me at gordon1977@icloud.com real quick

Answer (score 1):

Serialize your form and send. In the server side unserialize it and insert to database

```
var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
```

Reference
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Cool. Never heard of this. So i "serialize" it so that all the inputs are turned into one string, right? And then I send that one string as a single data entry to MySQL, right? How do you reverse the process to populate a field? And how does this work when you have inputs that are created by the user and do not exist on the form when it loads?

Comment: You can append those inputs as hidden fields to the form and serialize

Comment: I was thinking I could store the string whole then call it when a user wants to edit the page, divide it into an array with the "&"s as dividing points and the break apart the combined inputField+value into separate Key and Values that can be put in fields with a loop. Does that sound like a good idea or do you think there is a better way?